# Why is it that lampblack repels water but graphite doesn't?

Tags: everyday-life, water, interactions

I have been playing around with lampblack recently, and one property that I particularly like in them is their Hydrophobicity. It's interesting to watch water drops just bouncing off the surface.

[image]

---

[image]

I reasoned that this was because lampblack was carbon, which is hydrophobic. I wondered if Graphite could also repel water since it was also made up of carbon. I took a pencil and made a thick patch of graphite on a paper and placed a water drop on it. But I couldn't see any hydrophobicity.

---

[image]

---

***Why is it that the lampblack repels water whereas graphite doesn't; even though both are made up of carbon?***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the lampblack contains partially-burned hydrocarbons which are strongly hydrophobic.